# How to get many table entities from Azure Table Storage with multiple PKs?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a bunch of primary keys - tens of thousands, and I want to retrieve their associated table entities. All row keys are empty strings. The best way I know of doing so, is querying them one by one async. It seems fast, but ideally I would like to bunch a few entities together in a single transaction. Playing with the new Storage Client, I have the following code failing:

```cs
var sample = GetSampleIds(); //10000 pks

var account = GetStorageAccount();
var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("myTable");

//I'm trying to get first and second pk in a single request.
var keyA = sample[0];
var keyB = sample[1];

var filterA = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, keyA);
var filterB = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, keyB));

//filterAB = "(PartitionKey eq 'keyA') or (PartitionKey eq 'keyB')"
var filterAB = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filterA, TableOperators.Or, filterB);
var query = new TableQuery<TweetEntity>().Where(filterAB);

//Does something weird. I thought it might be fetching a range at one point.
//Whatever it does it doesn't return. Expected the following line to get an array of 2 items.
table.ExecuteQuery(query).ToArray()

// replacing filterAB in query with either filterA or filterB works as expected
```

Examples always show CombineFilters working on PK and then RK, but this is of no use to me. I'm assuming that this is not possible.

### Question

Is it possible to bundle together entities by PK? I know the maximum filter length is 15, but even 2 is a potential improvement when you are fetching 10,000 items. Also, where is the manual? Can't find proper documentation anywhere. For example MSDN for CombineFilters is a basic shell wrapping less information that intellisense provides.

Comment: I think TPL Dataflow library will speed this up, especially if you can increase the max concurrency above 1.  I'm experimenting with this in the 2.0 client.  Haven't gotten it to work yet...

Comment: @makerofthings7 Actually async is working very well and saturates my connection. Problem is that I still have to download headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr:  sounds like you need to rethink your partitioning strategy.  Unique, non-sequential IDs are not good PKs when you commonly have to query or work on many.  More:

Partition Keys are not meant to be 'primary' keys really.  They are more thought of as grouped, closely related sets of data that you want to work with.  You can group by id, date, etc.  PKs are used to scale the system - in theory, you could have 1 partition server per PK working on your data.

To your question:  you won't get very good performance doing what you are doing.  In fact, OR queries are non-optimized and will require a full table scan (bad).  So, instead of doing PK = "foo" OR PK = "bar", you really should be doing 2 queries (in parallel) as that will get you much better performance.

Back to your core issue, if you are using a unique identifier for a particular entity and describing that as a PK, then it also means you are not able to be working on more than 1 entity at time.  In order to work on entit(ies) you really need a common partition key.  Can you think of a better one that describes your entities?  Does date/time work?  Some other common attribute?  Those tend to be good partion keys.  The only other thing you can do is what is called partition ranging - where your queries tend to be ranged on partition keys.  An example of this is date-time partition keys.  You can use file ticks to describe your partition and end up with sequential data ticks as PKs.  Your query can then use > and < queries to specify a range (no OR).  Those can be more optimized, but you will still get potentially a ton of continuation tokens.

Comment: Thanks dunnry. Since I wrote the post, I got the OR query to work without the duplication, and the performance was - as you suggest - abysmal. I appreciate the stab in the dark at my poor choice of partition keys, but I've read some whitepaper on pk choice a while back, and I'm sure that I'm not making a mistake. My problem is simple - I want to group my random reeds into batches, so that I don't have to download costly headers. I'm currently at 500 bytes of header/chatter to each 5000 bytes of data. So I was hoping to group some entities, to reduce download time.

Answer (score 0):

As dunnry has mentioned in his reply, the problem with this approach is that OR queries are horribly slow. I got my problem to work without the storage client (at this point, I'm not sure what's wrong with it, let's say it's a bug maybe), but getting 2 entities separately without the OR query turns out to be much(!) faster than getting them with the OR query.